# Velocity for thermal ratchet

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am attempting to solve a problem for the velocity of a ratchet consisting of bolts length $L$ apart, with each bolt storing potential energy $ε$ and for a load $f$ on the ratchet. As the ratchet passes each bolt it is released. This problem considers an ensemble of $M$ ratchets with a probability distribution $P(x, t)$.

I was first solved the Smoluchowski equation to determine $P$ and then find the current $J$. As the current can be thought of as the average number of ratchets passing a given point in space per unit time, I assumed the velocity would be $v=JL$. However, the solution I am given states that the velocity is $v=\frac{JL}{\int^{L}_{0}{MP(x)}dx}$ i.e. my answer divided by the average number of ratchets in that interval.

Could someone explain why this is the correct velocity and how velocities for such systems can be thought about more generally?